# Ionic 1 resource loading issue

Tags: ionic-framework

[image]

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : none
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.11.4
npm   : 3.10.10
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

> I got this kind of list of issues when I run "ionic serve" command.How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like its unable to locate any package. Have you done "npm install"?

Comment: I got this when run npm install------->

npm WARN JSLink@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN JSLink@0.0.1 No license field.